# Large files download issue on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

This issue is driving me crazy.

I want to export a pdf report generated by iTextSharp.

I have an ASP.NET Web API project where I have my code that generates the PDF file.

I'm calling the API using jQuery using post method to send some parameters, get the query result based on those filters and export them.

Everything works fine on both IE and FireFox. The issue is related to Google Chrome when it comes to files larger than 5MB. The process finishes but I get "Download failed - Network error" from chrome.

The problem seems to be much more related to the javascript part as the byte array returns correctly.

Any help regarding this please ?

My ASP.NET Web Api method code :

```
[HttpPost]
public byte[] ExportPDFRequestsList(RequestFilter filter)
{
    //Method contains the logic of export that has no issues
    return RequestsService.ExportPDFRequestsList(filter);
}
```

My javascript code to download the file :

```
$.when(
        //jQuery ajax post method -- works fine
        AppObj.JsonCall("Post", exportPDFRequestsListUrl, true, parameter)

    ).then(function (response) {
        var newdata = "data:application/pdf;base64," + escape(response);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        //build download link:
        a.href = newdata;
        a.setAttribute("download", "Requests.pdf");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        setTimeout(function () {

            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");

            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null
          );
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            document.body.removeChild(a);

        }, 999);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this library that solved my problem :

http://danml.com/download.html